# How to iterate over HTML content in ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs

I have an API which returns me the response as an array for emails, which are actual email bodies (with HTML tags and escape characters and styling).

If its a single HTML body like this -> "content", I can easily create an element and set its innerHTML to this value, but I need to iterate over list of strings and show them in the page, I am working with ReactJS

Looking for options to do so, please suggest some solution for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `this.state.emailList` is an array of emails you would do it like this

```
state = {
    emailList : [
        "<div>email text</div>",
        "<div>email text</div>"
    ]
}
```

In your render function you would do this.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.emailList.map (
                email => (<p  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: email}}></p>)
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

.map is used to map through a list of item in javascript and it takes a callback function which returns the current element `email`.

dangerouslySetInnerHTML is used to display external HTML content in react

Hope this helps

Comment: Why the downvotes, this is the right solution. Though i must say that the idea of rendering an application using dangerouslySetInnerHTML from an API that returns email markup sounds live very bad practice.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot :)